# How to write SQLite trigger to get timestamp AFTER insert statement is committed

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I set up a SQLite database to store hand-written text notes, using this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Journal (
  entry_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  create_date TEXT DEFAULT (datetime()),
  edit_date TEXT,
  entry_text TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I use the [edit() function](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#the_edit_sql_function) to enter text records interactively using the sqlite3 CLI. It opens a text editor, I type my content and after closing the editor, the content will be committed:

```
sqlite> insert into Journal (entry_text) values(edit('','nano'));
```

I also created a trigger which should save the editing date and time AFTER I finished typing and closed the editor. Using this approach, one could infer how it long it took to write each entry. But I am struggling to get the correct timestamp **after** the editing is done and the text is inserted into the table.

Here is this approach which did not work, resulting in *create_date* and *edit_date* being always the same:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_edit_date AFTER INSERT ON Journal
  BEGIN
    UPDATE Journal SET edit_date = datetime() WHERE entry_id = new.entry_id;
  END;
```

I assume the call to datetime() is already done when the trigger is parsed and not after the insert action as intended from me.  Does anyone have an idea how this can be changed, i.e. how can I automatically commit the time exactly AFTER the INSERT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [sqlite3 date and time functions doc](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

> The 'now' argument to date and time functions always returns exactly the same value for multiple invocations within the same [sqlite3_step()](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) call.

One possible solution:

- change the trigger to `AFTER UPDATE`
- insert a "blank" row
- *update* the row `WHERE entry_id = last_insert_rowid()` and do the editing

Comment: I checked the clock and in my case both "start" and "end" datetime are equal to the start time. I was expecting the trigger will only run when the INSERT transaction is done and also run its datetime() function then.

Comment: Sorry, bad testing (or eyesight :). I expected the dates to be the same and they were. Perhaps the reason is found in [this post](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Datetime-Transactions-CLI-td98950.html#a98958) which says "_'now' is frozen at the time a transaction begins_". I will emend the answer.

Comment: Thank you, that is valuable information! That means, in my original attempt both insert and update from trigger happen in the same _sqlite3_step()_ call. Your solution breaks it up into 2 step calls by first inserting a blank row. Somewhat hidden or non-obvious though is the fact that in the first case, the timestamp will be from "start" of insert whereas in second case it will be at the end of the update.

Comment: Suspect that is because of the default value on create_date, which changes when datetime() is first evaluated.